# There is already an object named in the database error message when i try and change the order by to ascending

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to manipulate the order by of a view to order by Asc instead of Desc. In the query itself of the view it does not have an order by, but when i look at the cost plan for this view it seems like it is defaulting to order by ServiceCallID Desc, which i do not want. The table that the order by field comes from is being ordered by desc in the view but the table does have a clustered index on the table and it is in Asc order, which i am assuming is why the cost of this Sort for the view is at 36%. i am trying to bring down this cost, so the query wait time will be less than what it currently is.

When i try and make a change to the view by adding an order by in Asc order, to hopefully change the order by it gives me the error message 'there is already an object named in the database'.

Why am i getting this error message when i try to change this view? Also, is there a way for me to change this default order by for this view so i can get it to order by in Ascending order, instead of its default Descending order?

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.ServiceCalls.ServiceCallID, dbo.Contracts.ContractID, dbo.Contracts.Area, dbo.Jobs.JobName, dbo.Customers.CustomerName, dbo.Contracts.ContractType
FROM            dbo.Customers WITH (READPAST) INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Jobs WITH (READPAST) ON dbo.Customers.CustomerID = dbo.Jobs.CustomerID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Contracts WITH (READPAST) ON dbo.Jobs.JobID = dbo.Contracts.JobID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.ServiceCalls WITH (READPAST) ON dbo.Contracts.ContractID = dbo.ServiceCalls.ContractID
WHERE        (dbo.ServiceCalls.ScheduleDate > DATEADD(day, 0, GETDATE() - 500))
```

[image]

```
select
    object_name(m.object_id), m.*
from
    sys.sql_modules m
where
    m.definition like N'%vwMainCboServiceCallID%'
```

Comment: Remove the `TOP (100) PERCENT` (which makes no sense) and see if that helps. A view should basically never have an `ORDER BY`. If you want the results in a specific order then you do that when you select from the view.

Comment: I suspect that the `ORDER BY` is there because of the `TOP`, you should remove it

Comment: The code you posted is the "meat" of the view?  Can you show how you're  trying to make the change?  It seems like it's trying to do a CREATE instead of an ALTER.

Comment: @Kalmino It looks like he's trying to change it through UI, not code (which is also probably part of the problem).

Comment: the error message means the view exists so as Kalmino mentioned if you are using CREATE it will fail with that message.  If you use ALTER it should modify and succeed.  Another alternative is to DROP and CREATE

Comment: i am right clicking on the view, design, then adding the order by in the views query and when i hit the save button the error message pops up. As you can see in the query there is not order by, but in the execution plan(picture) i posted there is an order by, which i do not know why? @Matt

Comment: when i pull up the design that 100 percent is not there normally @Lamak

Comment: I dont know why it is trying to create because i am trying to alter the view in the actual query of the view @Kalmino

Comment: @ETA how can it "not be there normally"?, what does that even mean?

Comment: make sure you dont have other windows open and are hitting save all lol

Comment: The Top Specifications is set to 'NO' and the Top is set to (NO) for this view, so i must have added there for some reason, so the Top (100) Percent does not normally show up.@Lamak

Comment: Top 100 percent will show up automatically if you add Order by to a view

Comment: TOP (100) PERCENT is added by the Query Design view editor when adding an ORDER BY clause.  Think of it as using ORDER BY in a cte it is required to use TOP

Comment: I am not hitting save all, i am just trying to save the specific view. thanks for the comment though. @JamieD77

Comment: why is there and order by in the execution plan when there is not one in the actual query and how do i change this? @Matt

Comment: the execution plan you posted clearly has an ORDER BY in the query

Comment: your execution plan shows the TSQL query has an order by.  I suspect you have a problem that @JamieD77 is leading you to where you are actually trying to modify an object that already exists as the error says.  Do you have a table valued function or something else with the same name?  What you are showing as being executed is not the same as your code you posted.

Comment: please look at the changes i made. i added a query that i am using to search all areas (i believe) where the view name is being used and it only shows up one time. @Matt

Comment: please look at the changes i made. i added a query that i am using to search all areas (i believe) where the view name is being used and it only shows up one time. @JamieD77

Comment: you should try editing the view using Script View as >> Alter To >> New Query Editor Window and see if you get an error when you run the output

Comment: you can query SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE '%vasdfsf%' to show you every type of object type_desc will tell you what type of object exists. Are you renaming the view when you are editing it or only adding order by?

Comment: i ran that and the only result was the view that i posted here and it says that view is in Desc order, which cant be because there is no order by on this view. could it be this query is being used in a Stored procedure? i am totally lost on why it is saying it is descending. @Matt

Comment: View been modified outside of your GUI window? Try scripting things as @JamieD77 mentioned.  You can script create/alter/drop and create and that will tell you what the definition is.  Get out of the GUI and just alter with TSQL for a minute until you get what you want then go back into the GUI and see if it matches

Comment: I tried doing it that way just right now and it is currently at 1 minute of trying to update this view, so it is not working. i do not know why it wont let me update this view? @JamieD77

Comment: I just tried editing it with an alter script and it is not wortking. currently at 3 minutes. @Matt

Answer (score 0):

Wait a second, I have no idea why you are not able to save the query, but then again I am not really sure what you are trying to do and where in the GUI you are attempting to do it....

However, you keep mentioning you are looking for why their is an `ORDER BY` in the `Execution Plan` and not in the `View Definition`.  The `Execution Plan` is showing the SQL statement that someone/where selected from the view and ADDED an `ORDER BY` statement.  It is NOT showing the select statement that defines the view itself which in your case you say does not have an `ORDER BY` statement.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.View1
AS
SELECT *
FROM
```

that is a view definition

Then someone uses that view and can do

```
SELECT *
FROM
  dbo.View1
```

No order by in exeuction plan but if they do:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  dbo.View1
ORDER BY
   SomeColumn
```

now the execution plan will have an order by in it.

So what is the source of your execution plan?

Comment: i get that. it makes sense that someone is calling this view with that order by. Is there a chance that this Execution plan is showing for a query in our Access db, or this is being used in the procedural code to call this db to extract the data?

Comment: I am not sure I followed your question but if you didn't see it in sys.sql_modules then it isn't in a procedure or function in your SQL database unless perhaps you have a CLR or Encrypted Proc/Function.  So that means it can be called from anywhere else that connects to your database.  MS Access, Excel, SSMS of another user endless potential and the only way to find it is to look at anything that connects......

Comment: if we do have a CLR or Encrypted Proc/Function how would i find it so i can change it? @Matt

Comment: I figured it out. i will post the solution in a little. i appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

In our access database we had a field calling this view in the Row Source. So i went into the Row Source and took out the order by, because it is already being ordered in Ascending order. I was confused, because i did not know SSMS would show execution plans for queries in MS Access. Now i know. Thank you for your help and time.